# The parameter returns its name and not its value

Tags: asp.net, parameter-passing, code-behind, formview

What's wront with this code? IDuser_par doesn't return its DefaultValue which is the user ID. I get instead the string name which is "FormView_parameter".....!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                string userid = User.Identity.GetUserId();  
                Parameter IDuser_par = new Parameter();
                IDuser_par.Name = "FormView_parameter";
                IDuser_par.Type = TypeCode.String;
                IDuser_par.DefaultValue = userid;
                SqlDataSource_userdetails.SelectParameters.Add(IDuser_par);
                Response.Write(IDuser_par); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.parameter.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> > The ToString method returns the Name property of the Parameter object. If the Parameter object has no name, ToString returns String.Empty.

If you are writing your parameter as the response to the request, then the value sent will be the name of the parameter. Perhaps you are trying to actually *do* something with it?